# Web app screen orientation lock: Orientation lock failed

Tags: javascript, screen-orientation

I have used several methods from other questions to try to lock the screen orientation for my web app, but the lock orientation always fails.  Here is my code:

```
// lock orientation to portrait
window.screen.lockOrientationUniversal = window.screen.lockOrientation || window.screen.mozLockOrientation || window.screen.msLockOrientation;

if (window.screen.lockOrientationUniversal("portrait")) {
    console.log("Orientation locked to portrait");
} else {
    console.log("Orientation lock failed.");
}
```

I have also tried this with just `screen.` instead of `window.screen.` and get the same thing.  Note that this is being tested on the latest Firefox for Android and that the web-app is not a full-screen app.

I also get the following message:

> Use of the orientation sensor is deprecated.

Which makes sense as the [Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation) mentions that it is deprecated.  What is the latest supported way to do this?

Comment: According to MDN, it's deprecated.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan  Is there a newer way to do this?

Comment: The second sentence of the cited MDN documentation says:  "The ScreenOrientation.lock() method should be used instead."

Comment: @Amy `ScreenOrientation.lock("portrait")` and `window.ScreenOrientation.lock("portrait")` give `TypeError: ScreenOrientation.lock is not a function`.  Do you know how I can access the ScreenOrientation interface

Comment: These are experimental APIs.  It might not be available for your platform.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=screen-orientation

Comment: As Firefox is unsupported, then there's no way to lock orientation as the new method is unsupported and the old method is deprecated.  That's too bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.) Screen.lockOrientation is deprecated (as seen in the MDN link you provided), so the code you have probably won't work in most modern browsers.

2.) ScreenOrientation is just the interface, which is why `ScreenOrientation.lock("portrait")` does not work. Basically, ScreenOrientation is the thing in the background that tells the browser how the screen orientation object should be built (similar to prototypes in JavaScript), but it is not the object itself.

In modern browsers, you can access the global screen orientation like this:

`var myScreenOrientation = window.screen.orientation;`

(source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation)

Later you can lock the orientation with this:

`myScreenOrientation.lock("portrait");`

and unlock it with

`myScreenOrientation.unlock();`

The .lock() method returns a Promise if you want to do anything with that, but it's outside the scope of this question, so I'll just mention that it exists.

3.) Another possible issue: under current standards, many browsers will REQUIRE that a page be in fullscreen mode to lock a device's orientation. Since your web app is not fullscreen this will likely also prevent the orientation being locked. (see 5.3 of the web standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/)

Comment: Have done this but got an error: Unhandled Rejection (NotSupportedError): Operation is not supported.                                                                                                                   Code:  const orientation = window.screen.orientation
    orientation.lock('portrait')

Comment: That is not an issue with the code, but a restriction by the browser you are using (where the vendor, for instance, considers orientation lock a UX issue, a security concern, or unnecessary in a desktop browser). This reference shows you which browsers should work: https://caniuse.com/screen-orientation

Comment: Why not just answer with window.screen.orientation.lock("portrait") for us simple folk instead of introducing another layer of complexity?

Comment: BTW, window.screen.orientation.lock("portrait") did not work for me on an Android phone.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore on a current Chrome Browser. Say what you want, but developing websites for mobile devices is still a f***** pain in the a**. Can't wait until all the tiny mobile screens can finally unfold into a useful screen with enough space to show more than just a fancy tiktok video...

Comment: Looks like the page needs to be in fullscreen mode in order for locking the orientation to work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock